# Usar ob_start para evitar crear archivos zip y obtener su contenido

Tags: php, xml, base64, sha256, gzip

Tengo este código que crea un archivo ".zip" y dentro de él un archivo ".xml" obtenido de una cadena. Como se ve en el ejemplo más adelante, obtengo su información y la convierto a base64 y hash. El código es funcional. Lo que quiero ahora es usar "ob_start()" para no tener que crear el archivo ".zip", no se si alguien me podría ayudar con un ejemplo básico, saludos...

```
<?php
$content = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Catalog><Book id="bk101"><Author>Garghentini, Davide</Author><Title>XML Developers Guide</Title><Genre>Computer</Genre><Price>44.95</Price><PublishDate>2000-10-01</PublishDate><Description>An in-depth look at creating applicationswith XML.</Description></Book><Book id="bk102"><Author>Garcia, Debra</Author><Title>Midnight Rain</Title><Genre>Fantasy</Genre><Price>5.95</Price><PublishDate>2000-12-16</PublishDate><Description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queenof the world.</Description></Book></Catalog>';
$route = './temp/';
$name  = 'facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xml.zip';
$file  = "{$route}{$name}";

// CREATE ZIP
$zp   = gzopen($file,'w9');
gzwrite($zp,$content);
gzclose($zp);
// READ ZIP
$fp     = fopen($file,'rb');
$binary = fread($fp,filesize($file));

$res = [
    'archivo'     => base64_encode($binary),
    'hashArchivo' => hash('sha256',$binary),
];
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Eres consciente que no estás creando un archivo `.zip` si no un archivo `.gz`? Muchos compresores lo abrirán sin problema, pero ten en cuenta que un archivo gzip no es un contenedor de múltiples archivos como el formato ZIP.

Comment: He redactado una respuesta con una solución a tu problema, espero que sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: No me gusta tu nombre, pero bueno. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que buscás? Un ejemplo del resultado que estás buscando, por que no se entiende mucho.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de usar `ob_start()`, ¿por qué no envías los datos directamente al navegador usando la función [`gzencode()`](https://php.net/gzencode)?

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso:

```
<?php
$content = '...';

/* Comprimimos el contenido de $content */
$datos = gzencode($content);

/* Tu código: */
$res = [
    'archivo'     => base64_encode($datos),
    'hashArchivo' => hash('sha256', $datos),
];
print_r($res);
```

Yo te recomendaría realizar el envío directo a través de descarga o compresión del navegador:

```
<?php
/* Envío comprimido al navegador */
//header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
/* Descarga como archivo adjunto */
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="archivo.gz"');

/* Enviamos al navegador la cadena comprimida en GZIP */
echo $datos;
```

Pero todo depende del uso que le quieras dar o cómo llamas a este script PHP.

Comment: no entiendo el comentario XD

Comment: ok... pero nada de eso era necesario... XD